# how to get json data based on html values using jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, background-image

I am a beginner in jquery, but I want to finish my project.

I need your help guys, I want if I make html

```
<li value="bca"></li>
<li value="bni"></li>
<li value="bri"></li>
<li value="mandiri"></li>
etc....
```

jquery gets json data based on the html value. then after getting it, I want to add the style **background-image** attribute based on that li value, the result will be like this

```
<li style="background-image:url("images/bca.png");" value="bni"></li>
```

this is the json file

```
[
   {
     "id": "bca",
     "image": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-DzsioYaEw00/XJx4ldwgXbI/AAAAAAAAFOA/6xR4vKNHJnYPzyAmN_sike27rzTozXW8QCLcBGAs/h110/bca.png"
   },
   {
     "id": "bni",
     "image": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Km8RS__aFmY/XJx4lSZom7I/AAAAAAAAFOE/D6BYDFfRpUQdKILGREKGtKN8lLsjMijzACLcBGAs/h107/bni.png"
   },
   {
     "id": "bri",
     "image": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-_si-RcoPgn8/XJx4laAI9DI/AAAAAAAAFN8/H6p0uAGp5LsjeETFJCO0wrX0IVRUMRsOQCLcBGAs/h71/bri.png"
   },
   {
     "id": "mandiri",
     "image": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-7wME_gGOqlE/XJx4nKuMKoI/AAAAAAAAFOQ/e_g1zof81zA4RtoLvhXId-u5bbwynm2fgCLcBGAs/h105/mandiri.png"
   }
]
```

this my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('https://vhlan.com', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, icon) { // "icon" to get data from json file example icon.image
    // I don't know this part
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: `li` have no `value` attribute. **That is invalid HTML.** Use `data-value` instead, or rather, according to your JSON, use `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/yrgg4', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, icon) { 
            $("li[value='" + icon.id + "']").css("background", "url(" + icon.image + ") no-repeat");
      });
    });
  });
```

More : visit [this](https://jsfiddle.net/t6eo13b4/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Change your attribute to data-value. Value is no valid HTML data attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/yrgg4', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, icon) { // "icon" to get data from json file example icon.image
      // Select based on attribute value.
      // Use css() to add icon to background-image
      $("[data-value='" + icon.id + "']").css("background-image", "src(" + icon.image + ")");
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Downvoted for two reasons: 1. Only code, no explanation. 2. Does not address the invalid attribute problem.

Comment: Edit: Changed data attribute, explanation is in comments.